# Odd sqlite3 behavior for WHERE clause on TEXT column

Tags: sqlite

So, I've got a table.

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE data(date int primary key, temp text, humi text, co2 text, coarse int);
```

It's got some data, and using a WHERE condition on a TEXT column does what I'd expect:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM data WHERE temp > 26;
date        temp        humi        co2         coarse
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1569962962  26.01       30.97       530.34      1
1569963029  26.05       30.91       528.57      0
1569963097  26.05       30.87       530.16      0
1569963164  26.09       30.83       530.37      1
1569963232  26.09       30.84       530.75      0
1569963300  26.13       30.77       532.51      0
```

It also does what I expect when I give it a condition none of the rows match:

```
sqlite> select * from data where temp > 99;
sqlite>
```

*Unless* I use 100, or 1000, etc. Then it ignores the WHERE and gives me every row:

```
sqlite> select * from data where temp > 100;
date        temp        humi        co2         coarse
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1569967795  25.99       31.65       558.03      1
1569967863  26.01       31.60       558.78      0
1569967930  26.02       31.64       557.77      0
1569967998  26.01       31.65       556.68      1
1569968067  26.02       31.63       557.31      0
1569968134  26.04       31.64       560.01      0
1569968201  26.08       31.66       559.84      1
1569968268  26.05       31.66       563.95      0
1569968335  26.08       31.70       562.86      0
1569968403  26.09       31.69       563.85      1
1569968471  26.09       31.73       565.58      0
1569968539  26.11       31.69       566.04      0
1569968607  26.13       31.69       564.95      1
1569968674  26.13       31.62       565.51      0
1569968742  26.16       31.63       567.40      0
1569968810  26.16       31.60       568.38      1
[snip]
```

I, of course, discovered this by doing a DELETE operation with a WHERE clause to remove some bad data. It's okay, I've mostly stopped crying now. (The historical sensor data was not important) But why the behavior on multiples of 10? I assume it's doing something too-clever with flexible typing, but I don't see where.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you are doing a textual comparison (due to temp having a TEXT column affinity) so 1 is lower than 200 (i.e. the character 1 is lower than the value 2 so the other characters are insignificant).

You need to force a numerical comparison and this can be done by **CAST**ing e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE CAST(temp AS REAL) > 99;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE temp > CAST(99 AS REAL);
```

You may wish to have a look at [CAST expressions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr)

If the column type of the **temp** column were REAL as per

```
CREATE TABLE data(date int primary key, temp REAL /*<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED */, humi text, co2 text, coarse int);`
```

then the **CAST** would not be required.

Comment: I was going to say I set all the data columns to TEXT to get around sqlite's inexplicably low REAL precision, but then I read the [datatypes documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) again and discovered that they aren't stored as 8 bit floats, but 8 *byte* floats! Aaargh.

Comment: @SamuelBierwagen :)